# Laravel Middleware access protected values

Tags: laravel, controller, middleware

i wrote my own User-Role System, but i dont know how to implement the verification in my middleware routes.

The middleware class is calling on every request.

I recive the $request->user() but i can not access the attributes to verify if the user has the correct permissions.

My middleware controller looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Activation;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;

class AccountMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Sentinel::findByCredentials([
            'login' => $request->user()->attributes['email']
        );
        ...
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It doesnt work.

If I trie to dump the $request->user() i can see all properties but there are protected. 
What do i need to change, to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing Eloquent model properties is done via accessors, in this case via the [`__get` magic method](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.magic.php). So you don't need to access them through the `$attributes` property array, all you need is this:

```
$request->user()->email;
```

The above will return the user email because the [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__get`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3445-L3454) method already fetches the specified attribute automatically.

---

If you like, you can even define your own [Accessors or Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators) to modify attribute values when reading or writing them to the database.